# How i can change Top menu links magento?

Tags: php, magento

I need some help, I hope someone can help me.

I have a website with the domain www.liger.com.mx .When you enter to this website you can see the top links are of the following words:

Mi Cuenta - Mi Lista De Deseos - Mi Carrito - Pagar - Entrar

But the link of the word "Pagar" is broken, it has double /onepage/onepage on the link. I'm tired of editing

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/link.phtml

and

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/checkout.xml

but i could'nt fix the link error, i hope anyone here can help me, thanks for your time!

Comment: What are you looking to accomplish, the pagar "pay" link takes me to the checkout page. Which is a valid link,  where are you wanting it to go?

Comment: Im solved it! thanks for ur help :D